# How to make <Polyline /> follow roads in react-native-maps with HERE API

Tags: react-native, here-api, polyline, react-native-maps

I was able to make the request to HERE API and get the response, I put all the waypoints from leg to an array(latitude and longitude) and it does draw a polyline but it does not follow the road. It just goes trough buildings etc.

This is my Polyline component:

```js
<Polyline coordinates={this.state.route} strokeWidth={7} strokeColor="#2ecc71" geodesic={true} />
```

this.state.route is an array of coordinates which I got like this:

```js
axios.get(`https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={myappid}&app_code={myappcode}&waypoint0=geo!${from_lat},${from_long}&waypoint1=geo!${to_lat},${to_long}&mode=fastest;bicycle;traffic:disabled`).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.response.route);
      response.data.response.route[0].leg[0].maneuver.map((m) => {
        routeCoordinates.push({latitude: m.position.latitude, longitude: m.position.longitude});
      })
      console.log(routeCoordinates);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('ShowMap', {
        spot: chosenSpot,
        route: routeCoordinates,
      });  
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

And then I pass this array to my screen and put it in my state as `route`.

I expect it to draw a polyline over roads and not over buildings and stuff.

Here is an image to show you how it looks like(NOTE that blue lines are just to cover road names it has nothing to do with drawing a polyline):
[image: image of polyline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add an additional parameter to the calculateroute rest api:
**legAttributes=shape**

Then the rest api will return shape object containing the points along the roads.

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={myappid}&app_code={myappcode}&waypoint0=geo!${from_lat},${from_long}&waypoint1=geo!${to_lat},${to_long}&mode=fastest;bicycle;traffic:disabled&legAttributes=shape
```

Please see legAttributes in the documentation.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html

Comment: Thanks for help, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the answer first time but now I see that "shape" array. What do I do with it?